# how to send data into pop up blade view file in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

below is my controller code
how to show data on pop up blade file below

clicking on image i need show details passing form controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $result = Product::all();

        return view('admin/pos', compact('result'));
    }
```

and my blade file is belwo

```
 </div> @if(!empty($item)) @foreach($item as $list) @if($list->image!='') <a onclick="toggleModal1()">
            <img width="60px" src="{{asset('storage/media/'.$list->image)}}" style=" display:inline-flex" /></a> @endif
        @endforeach @endif
```

```
  <div class="fixed z-10 overflow-y-auto top-0 w-full left-0 hidden" id="modal1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center min-height-100vh pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
                <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity">
                    <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-900 opacity-75" />
                </div> <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen">&#8203;</span>
                <div class="inline-block align-center bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full"
                    role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">
                    <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                        <h3> <label>Product Name:</label></h3>
                        <br>
                        <h3> <label>Price:</label></h3>
                        <br>
                        <h3> <label>Barcode:</label></h3>
                        <br>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="button"
                                class="py-2 px-4 bg-gray-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-gray-700 mr-2"
                                onclick="toggleModal1()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my js file is

```
function toggleModal1() {
    document.getElementById('modal1').classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

Comment: Where is the html for the modal? Is it within your blade file as well, or are you bringing it in as an include from within your blade file?

Comment: If all the data you need is in $result, you can accomplish this with the use of jquery. You might need to assign the values in input type hidden + id then on jquery $("#hidden-id").val();. btw, The variable from controller is $result but the variable in blade is $list. Is this a typo?

Comment: i see each product have his model ... i think you will need to move popup code inside foreach and call model by ID

Answer (score -1):

you can pass data from controller like that
public function example(){$result = User::all(); return view('home', compact('result')); }

and use it result variable in blade file   to get the  popup

```
  @foreach($result as $value)
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$value->id}}">Open Modal</button>
  @endforeach
  <!-- Modal -->
  @foreach($result as $value)
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$value->id}}" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" id="{{$value->id}}">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>{{$value->name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  @endforeach
  
</div>
```